# Django Rest_Framework strange error can't import name SkippError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just started a project and installed django rest framework, then i have added it in `settings.py` 's installed apps.

then i run the server, it through me this error:

> File
>   "/home/pyking/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
>   line 125, in get_package_libraries
>       "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e) django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template
>   library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load
>   'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name
>   'SkipError'

When removing `rest_framework` from `installed apps`, the server works nice, but if add `rest_framework` in `settings.py` 's `installed apps` ,it doesn't work, and throw me above error

**Note: The project dont have any models, view, serializers file and anything. i new project with new apps,**

Can you please tell me why i facing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's no missprint - there's some dependencies missing. Create isolated virtualenv and install django and djangorestframework (maybe that's the problem you typed `pip install django_rest_framework` instead of djangorestframework).